# How to manipulate the ListView and layout in the android xml

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, android-linearlayout

Im trying to manipulate the  to do the following but its so far just lead to frustration... following is the poorly draw picture of what I am trying to accomplish:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZOta.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cEQk.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView


        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="419dp" >


    </ListView>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/FAP001"            
         />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="+1" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Im not sure if the listview is the way to go.. heck im not even sure if linearlayout is a good call.. Im trying to have end result close to what is on the 2nd image.
THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: a ListView is itself a scrolling view, so should not be contained in a ScrollView.  From your sketch, a ListView is definitely the right approach.

Comment: If what you want is a listview with several "configurable" fields in each item, maybe you should consider using listadapter and arrayadapter. Check this link. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html Hope is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place an ListView within a ScrollView. Thats not possible. Because then the ListView has got two options to scroll trough the content, as you will. And this won't work.

For more Information:

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/android-beginners/LRpLgGOy2Pc

If you want to have a ListView with 3 "sections" I would recommend you to create your own custom ListView with a Custom Adapter.

Here is a an Example of an custom ListView
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

You can just take this ListView and just have to modify the Adapter and the Row XML to your own needs.